# WebSocket IllegagStateException

Tags: jboss, websocket

I have tried out this websocket- example from github.com/eis/jboss-websocket-demo and get the following Exception:

08:16:46,008 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/websocket-web-app].[fi.eis.applications.jboss.poc.websocket.servlets.MyWebSocketServlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) Servlet.service() for servlet fi.eis.applications.jboss.poc.websocket.servlets.MyWebSocketServlet threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot upgrade connection

Actually I don't know what to do in order to get it done.
I would be very thankfull if someone could give me a hint what to do.

Thanks a lot and all the best!